# Vertical aligning the text in a container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align span elements which are adjacent to a floating element.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7vngc43/2/)

```css
.heading {
  background-color: tomato;
}
.heading::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.heading > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: beige;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Calibri;
}
.button {
  float: right;
  background-color: firebrick;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading"> <span> some icon here</span>
  <!--
 --><span>some text here</span>

  <div class="button">Go</div>
</div>
```

I am okay to change the HTML.

Some considerations: (*Added after seeing below answers*)

- Font size and height of the each child elements are different.
- If I use `display: table-cell`, the child elements width are stretching in the parent container. (*I need to just align the child elements vertically*)

PS: I am not looking for `display: flex` solution.

Comment: can you add the code snippet here itself in the question

Comment: @Jayababu I don't think that is necessary/mandatory. I provided the fiddle itself.

Comment: fiddle is blocked in my network,so only i asked..its not mandatory..np

Comment: I think you can use `line-height` on the span elements

Comment: @Jayababu updated. Simon M I could use that if the height of the container is fixed only.

Comment: @Mr_Green Even if the height of your container change, span elements would be centered, like this http://jsfiddle.net/w7vngc43/14/ but the button is not anymore centered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would love to go with the `display: table-cell;` solution but if it's just one line than you can use `line-height` here. (Just not to complicate the process using `display: table-cell;` as there are certain limitations such as you cannot use `margin` and stuff)

```
.heading {
    background-color: tomato;
    line-height: 40px;
}    

.button {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: firebrick;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7vngc43/12/) (`line-height` solution)

So basically what am doing is getting rid of your custom `padding` for the button and using a `line-height` instead. If you think you can have more than one line, than making both the sections as `display: table-cell;` will make much more sense.

---

As you commented a case where you have different `font-size` which doesn't make much sense to me, so a solution for that is to use `display: table-cell;` and tweak your markup a bit

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7vngc43/19/) (`display: table-cell;` solution)

```
<div class="heading"> 
    <div>
        <span> some icon here</span>
        <span>some text here</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="button">Go</div>
    </div>
</div>

.heading {
    background-color: tomato;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.heading > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.heading > div:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}

.heading span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.heading span:first-child {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.button {
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: firebrick;
}
```

Comment: I think I can't use this in my condition as the heights and font-size of the each child elements are different. http://jsfiddle.net/w7vngc43/13/

Comment: @Mr_Green Than you should go with the `display: table-cell;` solution as this case wasn't included in your question hence didn't considered

Comment: @Mr_Green Added the case as you wanted

Comment: Thanks, atlast I went with the bizarre solution of `line-height` which worked awesome. (_removed padding from button_)

Comment: I modified this solution without `line-height`. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/w7vngc43/22/).

Answer (score 1):

Add this in to your css:

```
    .heading span {
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to `display: table-cell` property

**as like this**

```css
.heading {
    background-color: tomato;
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}
/* clear fix */
 .heading::after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.heading > * {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: beige;
}
.button {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: firebrick;
}
/* my attempt to align */
 .heading::before {
    content:"";
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading"> <span> some icon here</span>
 <span>some text here</span>

    <div class="button">Go</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but `display: table-cell` is spreading the width of the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a padding and make sure the height of the button is set.

```
.heading .mytext {
  height: 20px;
  float: left;

  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


.button {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: firebrick;
```

}

with html

```
<div class="heading"> 
    <div class="mytext">
        <span> some icon here</span>
        <span>some text here</span>
    </div>

    <div class="button">Go</div>
</div>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/w7vngc43/20/

Answer (score 0):

I modified Mr.Alien's solution of `display: table-cell` without using `line-height`. Here is the code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="heading">
    <div class="left"> <span class="left-one"> some icon here</span>
 <span class="left-two">some text here</span>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <button class="button-cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button class="button-go">Go</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.heading {
    background-color: tomato;
}
.heading > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.left {
    width: 100%;
}
.left span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.left-one {
    font-size: 30px;
}
button {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: firebrick;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.right {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/w7vngc43/22/)**